# What is a difference with role in fabric CA and role in Endorsement Policy?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I'm using Hyperledger Fabric, I can confirm roles in fabric CA and Endorsement Policy.
Role in Fabric CA

> fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name admin2 --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=peer,user",hf.Revoker=true'

Role of Endorsement Policy

> peer chaincode deploy -C testchainid -n mycc -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"

1. what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`hf.Registrar.Roles` determines which identities you can register. In this case, you can register a peer or a user with admin2.

The endorsement policy determines which kind of endorsement an invoke will need. With `-P " AND ('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"` you will need endorsements from both organizations.